# See available users in Gitolite

Tags: gitolite

Sometimes it is not clear what username a certain gitolite user has. If people want to control access rights for their wild repos, they need to know the usernames. One obvious solution would be to ask them for their usernames.
In our environment the most common case is that the admin is asked for usernames, since sometimes the users themselves do not know their usernames.

This is a bit inconvenient and I would like to know whether is an easy solution, e.g. a command that displays all available usernames. If not, are there any suggestions on how to write such a script and how to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a new command 'usernames' that simply prints a text file that contains all usernames with respective real names. I put this file in the main directory of the gitolite-admin-repo. Only drawback is that this file requires manual updating after a new user is added.

Put this in `~/gitolite-source/src/commands/usernames`:

```
#! /bin/bash

cat $HOME/.gitolite/usernames.txt
```

Comment: Interesting. Looks simpler than my answer below. +1

Answer (score 1):

I think what he wanted was a way to list the user names assigned to *other* users.  His concern may be that the admin may have typo-ed the name when adding the pubkey file.  Say I send him my "id_rsa.pub".  He stores it as "sitram.pub" instead of "sitaram.pub".  As long as rights in the conf file are also similarly mis-spelled, you may not even realise this.

The person who wants to give access to his repos has only one choice: ask each of the people he wants to give access to run 'ssh git@host info' and report what username they see.

Partly it's a matter of information disclosure to allow a non-admin user to query all other usernames.

The other part is, if you're in HTTP mode or something, there really is no sane way to know who all the possible authenticated (authenticatable!) users are.  For ssh you could of course do something like this:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /-shell (.*?)"/' < ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Gitolite has a "list-users" command but that only knows the users who are already named in some access rule in the conf file.  Which is not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Gitolite (V3) has a list of [commands](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/cust.html#commands), including

```
ssh git@host info -h
ssh git@host perms -h
```

Which can help getting to the content of the gitolite config.

```
ssh git@host perms -l <repo>
```

Will list the current contents of the permissions file.

Comment: These commands still can not display any information about other users. With V2 it was possible to display the access permissions for all users. I am missing this feature in V3.

Comment: @mattmilten: true, you might need to modify https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/commands/perms then, in order to achieve like the '`info`' command in V2: https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/g2/src/gitolite.pm#L1198

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using

```
perl -le 'while(<>) {$h{$1}=1 if /-shell (.*?)"/};foreach (sort(keys(%h))){print $_;}' < ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

It is much the same as Sitaram's provided snippet, except it removes duplicates and sorts.